# Looking for annotated vector map of world?

Tags: vector, data, svg

I'm looking for an annotated vectorial (PS/SVG/...) map of the world (+countries).

Wikipedia contains many vectorial maps (e.g: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Blank_SVG_maps_of_the_world )but the paths are defined like that:

```
<path fill="#ccc" d="M98.171,199.174c-0.505-0.076-0.938-0.322-0...
```

... and I'd like to find an **identifier** so I can colorize a given country (using XSLT or another method....). Something like that:

```
<path id="JAPAN" fill="#ccc" d="M98.171,199.174c-0.505-0.076-0.938-0.322-0...
```

Answer (score 5):

This Political 'world map' available in vector and raster formats. Countries are individually selectable, as are country names.

Suggest EPS or AI (Illustrator format) that can be easily exported into SVG with the XSLT or XML Style Sheets.

[image]

Current version: 2.2 (2009)

http://www.vectorworldmap.com/

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention Wikipedia as a starting point I gather you're looking for free maps. You might try funnelling the [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) through [shp2svg](http://www.carto.net/svg/utils/shp2svg/) or [shapefile-to-svg](http://egb13.net/2009/07/shapefile-to-svg-translator-project/) and see it that results in something useful. [Convert Shapefiles Into SVG Format With Thematic Coloring](http://freegeographytools.com/2009/convert-shapefiles-into-svg-format-with-thematic-coloring) indicates that the latter maintains attribute identifier information.

If commercial offerings are ok http://www.mapresources.com/ seems to have good quality stuff, though I'm not sure about the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The resources suggested below are offer by the commercial website Fotolia (Phone number +1 (888) 674-2299) offering royalty free images, vectors, videos and logos.

The vectors are authored by StingerMKO.

---

Have a look at these maps.

Every country as single selectable Vector/Layer:

- [Detailed Worldmap - Weiß © StingerMKO #42626483](http://us.fotolia.com/id/42626483)
- [Detailed Worldmap © StingerMKO #42626289](http://us.fotolia.com/id/42626289?by=serie)

Comment: Hi Malte, welcome to GIS.se :) I hope you find our community useful and we are grateful to have your participation. This would be a better answer if it included more information. Examples of useful info include things like: name of author/publisher (the link or domain could change. If we know who created it we might be able to find the new home); free or commercial, license restrictions, etc.; size of data collection; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [World vector maps free](http://vectormap.info/category/free_vector_maps_downloads/free_vector_world_maps/) can help you, they have a small collection of free vector maps.

I just downloaded a world map with time zones there.

Answer (score -2):

Here, these vector maps has helped me a lot you could use it too for free http://vectormap.info/free-maps-for-all-designers-and-mappers :)

Comment: If you or [Lalu](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/83891/lalu) have any connection to the maps that you are promoting here then you need to disclose that in every answer you mention it in.